# how do we use an OR condition in jq filtering

Tags: jq

```
  "status" : "UP",
  "details" : {
    "Service1" : {
      "status" : "UP",
      "details" : {
        "Hbase" : {
          "status" : "UP",
          "details" : {
            "tableName" : "test1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Service2" : {
      "status" : "UP",
      "details" : {
        "commTableHbase" : {
          "status" : "UP",
          "details" : {
            "tableName" : "test2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
     "Service3" : {
      "status" : "UP",
      "details" : {
        "GraphDSE" : {
          "status" : "UP",
          "details" : {
             "graph" : {
              "status" : "UP",
              "details" : {
                "name" : "svoc"
              }}}}}}}}
```

Above is my json . I was using below to get the o/p

```
.details
| to_entries[]
| "Data service Status:", "\(.key)- \(.value.status)",
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~",
"Hbase status:",
 (.value.details[]
| "\(.details.tableName) - \(.status)" ),
"========================================"
```

but it's unable to pull the last array value as it doesn't have a tableName so I want to use "(.details.graph.details.name) - (.status)" ) in addition to what I have.

Comment: Please provide example input and output in your question.

Comment: What exactly is the "OR" condition you have in mind? An example would help clarify your requirements but it might be helpful if you described them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.details.tableName // .details.graph.details.name` where you previously used `.details.tableName` :

```
.details
| to_entries[]
| "Data service Status:", "\(.key)- \(.value.status)",
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~",
"Hbase status:",
 (.value.details[]
| "\(.details.tableName // .details.graph.details.name) - \(.status)" ),
"========================================"
```

It uses the [Alternative operator (//)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://) which returns its lefthand operand expect when it's null or false, in which case it returns its righthand operand.

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/BEQwq1punv).

Comment: I was using ?// above statement helps.